# Python class definition syntax

Tags: python, class

Is there a difference between

```
class A:
    ...
```

and

```
class A():
    ...
```

I just realized that a couple of my classes are defined as the former and they work just fine. Do the empty parenthesis make any difference?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The latter is a syntax error on older versions of Python. In Python 2.x you should derive from `object` whenever possible though, since several useful features are only available with [new-style classes](http://www.python.org/doc/newstyle/) (deriving from `object` is optional in Python 3.x, since new-style classes are the default there).

Comment: No longer true in python 3; all that deriving from `object` nonsense is taken care of automatically.

Comment: Was `class A()` ever a syntax error? The [Python 1.4 docs](https://docs.python.org/release/1.4/ref/ref7.html#REF23237) say it's fine, and those are the oldest docs still available on python.org.

Answer (score 150):

While it might not be syntactically incorrect to use the empty parentheses in a class definition, parentheses after a class definition are used to indicate inheritance, e.g:

```
class A(baseClass):
    ...
```

In Python, the preferred syntax for a class declaration without any base classes is simply:

```
class A:
    ...
```

Don't use parentheses unless you are subclassing other classes.

The [docs on the matter](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#class-definition-syntax) should give you a better understanding of how to declare and use classes in Python.

Answer (score 4):

A class definition is a bit different from a function/method definition.

The parentheses in class definitions are for defining from which class you inherit. You don't write def in front of it, and when you inherit from 'object' which is the default you don't need the parentheses for the definition.

So you can write either:

```
class C():
```

Or:

```
class C:
```

Function/method definitions always take parentheses, even if you don't define parameters. If you don't use them, you'll get a SyntaxError.

Later, after the definition of a class/function/method in the code, just writing the name will point you to the class/function/method.

If you want to call or access any of these, you'll need (), [], . or whatever.