# Why are parenthesis optional when defining a class, but mandatory when defining a function?

Tags: python, function, class, syntax

In Python, defining a function with an empty parameter list requires a set of empty parenthesis.  However, defining a `class` with the default superclass does not require a set of empty parenthesis; rather, those are optional, and appear to be uncommon.  Why is it so?

*See also: [Python class definition syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4109552/974555)*.

Comment: Why shouldn't it be so?  Classes are not functions.  Voting to close because I think that this is an opinion based question.  I doubt there is an objective answer.

Comment: I'm on board that a no-args function shouldn't require an empty set of braces, but that's my opinion and simply not the way python works.  Other languages like ruby take optional-parentheses to the extreme, and it has... upsides and downsides.

Comment: [In 2005](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2005-February/051712.html) empty parentheses were not allowed.

Comment: Voting to reopen because I think that there is an objective, historical reason for Python's behavior (even if it has changed a few times). Historical knowledge of a programming language helps you understand how to use it better.

Comment: It's a language (syntax) design question.  There might be more to language design than opinions.

Comment: Although that design may be opinion unless you're Dutch.

Comment: "Classes are not functions." - everything in python is a name label. So, it is a very reasonable question. "Why is it so?" is not opinion based - the authors had a motivation for this design (while it is their *opinion*, it is only one certain opinion). Voted to reopen.

Comment: @gerrit in celebration of the ban being lifted, I expanded my answer!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think the answer to your question is simply syntax.  That is just the way Python is set up, but my take on how it got that way is:

I would think functions came out of mathematics things like:

```
f(x) = x
```

So when computer programming languages were being created there seems to have been some logical continuity from analog mathematics into programming languages.

Classes on the other hand are more constructs of Computer Science, and repetitive memory management, so they were not created in such a fashion, but because they have a *functional* quality to them, they were given similar notation.

For Python, I will use the term `method` for `function` as that is the usual lingo...

I understand your argument that both a `class` and `method` should be allowed to be defined using a short-cut in the no argument case:

- for `class`es when there is no inheritence
- for `method`s when there are no arguments

One reason I can think of is for consistency across usage and definition.  Let's look at some examples:

definition:

```
def funcA():
    return 0

def funcB(arg):
    return arg
```

and you want to call that funciton:

```
>>> funcA()
>>> functB("an argument")
```

and

```
>>> f1 = funcA
>>> f2 = funcB
>>> f1()
>>> f2("another argument")
```

to pass references and call them.

The syntax of the paranthesis between `method` declaration is consistent with calling the `methods`.

You need to put those empty parenthesis otherwise the interpreter will give you a reference to the `method`, and not actually call it.

So one benefit is it makes your code very clear.

definition:

```
class classA:
    pass

class classB(object):
    pass
```

usage:

```
# create an instance
my_instance_of_A = classA()
my_instance_of_B = classB()

# pass a reference
my_ref_to_A = classA
my_ref_to_B = classB

# call by reference
new_A = my_ref_to_A()
new_B = my_ref_to_B()
```

Here there is no change in behavior with regards to whether the `class` inherits or not, its calling behavior is dictated by what its internal or inherited `__init__` method is defined as.

I think the current set up of requiring the empty `()` makes the code more readable to the untrained eye.

If you really really really want to do what you ask, there is a workaround... you could always do this:

```
func = lambda: "im a function declared with no arguments, and I didn't use parenthesis =p"
```

which can be called:

```
>>> func
<function <lambda> at 0x6ffffef26e0>
>>> func()
"im a function declared with no arguments, and I didn't use parenthesis =p"
```

But the [python holy book says No](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations)

Comment: This question needs a simpler answer.

Comment: @carloswm85 My first sentence is the simplest answer I think there is.  The great thing about stack overflow is that you can add an answer as well!