# NameError: name 'start_time_of_the_script' is not defined

Tags: python, function

```
import time
import datetime

class TimeCounter():

    def startTime():

        start_time_of_the_script = time.time()

    def endTime():

        end_time_of_the_script = time.time()
        process_time_in_seconds = end_time_of_the_script - 
start_time_of_the_script
        print(str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=process_time_in_seconds)))

def main():

    TimeCounter.startTime()
    TimeCounter.endTime()

main()
```

I know that I am doing some fundamental mistake using python functions. Would you mind sharing a solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to distinguish between *classes* and *instances*. Once you have defined `TimeCounter` as a *class*, you can create one or many *instances* of it. This is done below in the assignment `tc = TimeCounter()`, which creates a fresh instance of `TimeCounter` and assigns it to the variable `tc`.

When methods (functions) are called on instances of a class, the instance is passed to the method as a parameter, traditionally called *self*. So when the code below calls `tc.startTime()`, the `self` parameter in `startTime` will refer to the `tc` instance. Also, when `startTime` sets `self.start_time_of_the_script`, it is creating a new property of the `tc` instance - which is then read again in `endTime`.

```
import time
import datetime

class TimeCounter:  # Parentheses not necessary

    def startTime(self):  # Note self parameter

        self.start_time_of_the_script = time.time()  # Set a property of the instance

    def endTime(self):  # Note self parameter

        end_time_of_the_script = time.time()  # This is a local variable
        process_time_in_seconds = end_time_of_the_script - self.start_time_of_the_script
        print(datetime.timedelta(seconds=process_time_in_seconds))

def main():

    tc = TimeCounter()  # Create a fresh instance of TimeCounter and assign to tc
    tc.startTime()  # Call method startTime on the tc instance
    tc.endTime()

main()
```

Comment: Thanks. It did work! However, another question came up as; why we also don't write self.end_time_of_the_script for: end_time_of_the_script and self.process_time_in_seconds for : process_time_in_seconds. why it does't give any error when we don't.? –

Answer (score 1):

You can assign values you want to retrieve later to `self.` like the following:

```
import time
import datetime

class TimeCounter:

   def startTime(self):

        self.start_time_of_the_script = time.time()

    def endTime(self):

        self.end_time_of_the_script = time.time()
        self.process_time_in_seconds = self.end_time_of_the_script - self.start_time_of_the_script
        print(str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=self.process_time_in_seconds)))
```

[The self variable explained](https://pythontips.com/2013/08/07/the-self-variable-in-python-explained/)

Comment: In the above example we have not written object inside of **class TimeCounter():** while creating the TimeCounter class and the code did work. I wonder in which situations do we have to write **object** inside of class paranthesis?

Comment: @questioneer1 Yes parentheses are used when a class is subclassing another class. It is not necessary here it seems. I referenced this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4109552/python-class-definition-syntax. It looks like we have both learned something here. I will remove that from my answer.

Comment: And here is one more link that explains that further: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015417/python-class-inherits-object

Comment: Yes very important thing I have learned too. What if I wanted to call say for example the : **process_time_in_seconds** from python shell or from another function later on, what should I do? because it does not simply work like writing **process_time_in_seconds** in the shell as I am using functions in the classes..

Comment: You can retrieve class attributes from instances of the class after instantiation. So if your class instance is `tc` you can retrieve said value with `tc.process_time_in_seconds` .

Comment: Hmm. for the code most above it says : **NameError: name 'tc' is not defined** when I give **tc.process_time_in_seconds** to the shell

Comment: yes you would need to instantiate the class with `tc = TimeCounter()`

Comment: yes i do it under the **def main():** function already. like @vthorsteinsson given example .. should i do something else?