# Difference between 'class MyClass:' and 'class MyClass():'

Tags: python, oop

With or without parenthesis, is there a difference?

```
class Host:
def __init__(self, ip, elements):

class Interface():
def __init__(self, localIP, remoteIP, numHops, hops):
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python class definition syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4109552/python-class-definition-syntax)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no difference whatsoever, and any half-decent IDE will suggest you to "remove redundant parenthesis".

In Python 2 days there was a difference between `class Host` and `class Host(object)` (see [What is the difference between old style and new style classes in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54867/what-is-the-difference-between-old-style-and-new-style-classes-in-python)).

In Python 3, `class Host`, `class Host(object)` and `class Host()` are all equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, parentheses in class definitions are used to indicate *inheritance*:

```
class Interface(baseClass):
```

If your class does not inherit any properties from another object, then it is more natural to omit parentheses:

```
class Interface:
```